# AdMob consistently returns 'No fill from ad server.'

Tags: android, admob

I've an exiting app at Google Play and it's designed for families. 
I'm trying insert ads to the app using AdMob but I consistently get 'No fill from ad server.' when trying to load ads.

I've two other apps using AdMob for ~1 year and everything is working as expected and the issue happens only on the third exiting app for which I'm trying to add adds while it's already exists in the store.
I've tried to 'tag' the `adRequest` to be for children:

```
AdRequest prodModeAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true).build();   
m_adMobView.loadAd(prodModeAdRequest);
But this didn't help.
```

Trying to root cause the issue, I've tried to change the package name of the app at the AndroidMainfest and the ads start to appear. But this is an applicable solution for me as the application exists.

Just to mention that the application is active at Google Play and I'm trying to load ad units linked the the application at AdMob.

Did anyone fail on the same/a-similar issue? Any clue of how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

**No fill from Ad Server** means there is a problem in the app in Admob ( asyou said ads will be displayed when you changed the package name, so code is working fine), even your app is active on play store, maybe the problem in ads server which is Admob, try to contact Admob support and ask them what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It takes sometime to reflect created ad unit id in app. Wait for sometime and try to load. It happened to me and after half an hour my app displayed ads.

Answer (score -1):

**No fill from Ad Server** means that your request got to the ad server but the ad server has no ads for you at this point in time.

Because you are limiting yourself to ads designed for children there will be fewer ads available.

The best solution is to us mediation to try to find suitable ads from another network when none are available directly from AdMob.